# Making a timer in Javascript , starting from 00:00:00

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

with this following code

```
function clock(){
    /*var message = document.getElementById("timer");
    message.innerHTML = "The time is " + Date();
    */
    var msec = 00;
    var sec = 00;
    var min = 00;

    msec += 1;
    console.log(min + ":" + sec + ":" + msec);
    if (msec == 60) {
        sec += 1;
        msec = 00;
        console.log(min + ":" + sec + ":" + msec);
        if (sec == 60) {
            sec = 00;
            min += 1;
            console.log(min + ":" + sec + ":" + msec);
            if (sec % 2 == 0) {
                alert("Pair");
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec + ":" + msec;
}
```

What I wanted to do is a simple timer that starts on a window load, and every milisec it increments the up to 60, which by then resets to 0 and adds 1 to the seconds which when seconds reaches 60, goes to 0 and increments minutes by 1. Sorta like a stopwatch.

It seems I'm not incrementing properly but I don't know how to increment it.

I'm calling the function with a `setInterval` which I don't know if its right:

```
var  timer = setInterval(clock(), 1000);
```

Comment: Humm, you try to get milli second too. And you call your clock function all 1000milli second (1sec).. Isn't working ^^
And second stuff, 1s = 1000ms / 1s != 60ms

Comment: `msec` in the if statement should be 1000, not 60.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the function reference to `setInterval`, currently you are passing the return value of `clock()` which is `undefined` thus it has no impact.

Also you need to declare `msec`, `sec` and `min` variables out side `clock()` function.

```
var timer = setInterval(clock, 1000);
var msec = 00;
var sec = 00;
var min = 00;
```

```js
var timer = setInterval(clock, 1000);
var msec = 00;
var sec = 00;
var min = 00;

function clock() {
 msec += 1;
 if (msec == 60) {
  sec += 1;
  msec = 00;
  if (sec == 60) {
   sec = 00;
   min += 1;
   if (sec % 2 == 0) {
    alert("Pair");
   }
  }
 }
 document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec + ":" + msec;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: oh yes! but its still not incrementing at all, thos not entering the if cycles below